# CSF - Connection refused

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm using tomcat 9 and csf v12.08. When I try to open a connection on my web app (Java) like this (simple example):

```
URL url = new URL("url here");
url.openConnection();
```

I reiceve the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

And if I turn off the CSF there is no error.

I have tried using the default configuration of the CSF, but I still receive the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to open ports in CSF configuration. I'd expect that anyway. It's a firewall after all, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thanks ;)